# Merge HTML String

Tags: javascript, html, dom, merge

I am trying to find the best way to merge two HTML String in Javascript (JQuery/AngularJS) such as :

```
var context = '<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
     <ul id="list">
       <li>itemA</li>
       <li>itemB</li>
     </ul>
   </body>
</html>';
```

merged with :

```
var additionnalInfo = '<ul id="list">
       <li>itemC</li>
       <li>itemD</li>
     </ul>';
```

should modify **context** variable to :

```
'<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
     <ul id="list">
       <li>itemA</li>
       <li>itemB</li>
       <li>itemC</li>
       <li>itemD</li>
     </ul>
   </body>
</html>';
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do something like this, as long as your additional info contains only the elements you want to add (which you can easily strip down to).

```
var additionnalInfo = '<li>itemC</li>
                       <li>itemD</li>';

var list = getElementById('list');
list.innerHTML += additionalInfo;
```

**Edit**

If you must be able to match on several ids, then its possible you could use jQuery to iterate through all elements of a type (all lists for example), and just check the ids for equality, then append as above.  Ex:

```
var additionalInfo = $.parseHTML('<ul id="list"><li>itemC</li><li>itemD</li></ul>');
var elements = additionalInfo.find($('ul'));
var lists = $('ul').get();

elements.each(function(){
    var el = this;
    lists.each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id') == el.attr('id')){
            el.innerHTML += $(this).innerHTML;
        }
});
```

There are more efficient ways of doing this, but it should be a good basis for what you need.  Essentially just loop through all of the "parent" list elements in the additional html.  Compare those ids against the list ids within your existing html, and if they are the same, then append the new innerHTML to the existing list.

You can also make it more generic so that once you parse your html string, get the type of any element with an id, and do a find for that type.  A lot of ways to do this, its just a matter of applying the proper method of iterating through your data without wasting a ton of cycles.  Hope this helps a bit more.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is very important to keep the same identifier; So I have more complex HTML strings with more than 1 id info :)